# Why does pow() work without typing "using std::pow();" or "std::pow(x,y);"?

Tags: c++

I can use `pow()` with `#include <cmath>` and without the `using` keyword or the `::` operator. Why?

Comment: Because `cmath` makes available the C math functions, and C doesn't have namespaces.

Answer (score 4):

From `[headers]/4` of the standard.

> Except as noted in Clause 20 through Clause 33 and Annex D, the contents of each header *cname* is the
> same as that of the corresponding header *name.h* as specified in the C standard library (Clause 2). In the
> C++ standard library, however, the declarations (except for names which are defined as macros in C) are
> within namespace scope (6.3.6) of the namespace std. It is unspecified whether these names (including any
> overloads added in Clause 21 through Clause 33 and Annex D) are first declared within the global namespace
> scope and are then injected into namespace std by explicit *using-declarations* (10.3.3).

Basically, the standard allows functions within the `c` headers to be part of the global scope; however, they aren't required to be.

Comment: In other words, the shown program may work on some systems, and might not work on other systems.